# How to make a GenericeFunction<T> with "unknown" Type work?

Tags: c#

I have a function that prints me the data I get from an SQL select :

```
public static void PrintList(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (var row in entity)
            {
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(row));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

What I wanted to archieve is something like this:

```
GenerallHelperFunctions<result.GetType()>.PrintList(result);
```

But this is not working:

```
Using the generic type 'generic type' requires 'number' type arguments
```

Is there a way to use a "unknown" type for a generic function like this?

(If I specify the Type, it works as intended, but I usually don't know what type I have right now)

Comment: But why if that's the case? 
Just asking for the future, I really don't want to bother people.

Comment: It comes across as "I couldn't be bothered doing any work so I'm here to get you people to think for me". We're all volunteers here and it makes our job easier when the person asking does as much of the work as possible.

Comment: Yeah, true, I understand that, sorry.

Comment: @user3793935 : just removed the google line, hoping it stops the hater flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `<T>` after PrintList declaration

```
public static void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<T> entity)
{
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var row in entity)
    {
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(row));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Then the call could be:

```
GenerallHelperFunctions<MyType>.PrintList(result);
```

or even simpler because the compiler can infer (deduce) the type:

```
GenerallHelperFunctions.PrintList(result);
```

Actually you can have a generic class, but when you have the generic T in the parameter list, it's better to make the function generic instead of the class. So the T type can be inferred.

Answer (score 4):

No, generics need to be compile-time resolved. But you can just pass a non generic there:

```
    public static void PrintList(IEnumerable entity)
    {
        foreach (var row in entity)
        {
            var props = row.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(row));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Or, if you want to print only the properties of a specific type (not of the specific type of each row):

```
    public static void PrintList(IEnumerable entity, Type type)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var row in entity)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(row));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

And call it like:

```
GenerallHelperFunctions.PrintList(result, result.GetRowType());
```

Comment: Could also do `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: @nickzoum certainly, but since the generic is not used at all here, `IEnumerable` should be just as good

Comment: In this case yes, but not all classes/methods have a non generic option

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a type parameter, as others already pointed out, since you just need GetType() to get the type ^^.

You could wrapp it into a pair of extension methods to dump any objects contents whereever needed.

```
public static class ToLineExtension {
    public static string ToLine(this object instance) => 
            string.Join(" | ", instance.GetType().GetProperties()
              .Cast<PropertyInfo>().Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
              .Select(p => $"{p.Name} : {p.GetValue(instance)}"));
    
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToLines(this IEnumerable instances) {
        foreach (var instance in instances) {
            yield return instance.ToLine();
        }
    }
}

//invocation
//for enumerables
ITuple   t1  = Tuple.Create("Hello", 42, 12.5d, 25f, 300m);
ITuple   t2  = Tuple.Create(24, 21.5d, 52f, "World");
ITuple[] arr = { t1, t2 };

foreach (var line in arr.ToLines()) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
//for a single item:
Console.WriteLine(t1.ToLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah Thank you for the fast responses.
My mistake was, that I made my class generic too

```
class GenerallHelperFunctions**<T>**
        {
            public static void PrintList(IEnumerable<T> entity)
            {
                var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                foreach (var row in entity)
                {
                    foreach (var prop in props)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, 

prop.GetValue(row));
                        }
                        Console.Write

Line();
                }
            }
        }
```

I removed that and made it like this:

```
public static void PrintList<T>(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (var row in entity)
            {
                foreach (var prop in props)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} : {1} | ",prop.Name, prop.GetValue(row));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Now I can call it like I wanted to:

```
GenerallHelperFunctions.PrintList(result);
```

And it works.

Thank you guys for helping